# c# VSTO run VBA module from hard drive

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am using C# to build an Excel AddIn by VSTO, one thing I want to do is automatically import a VBA module which I wrote(a .bas file ) into Excel and run it when the user importing my Excel AddIn from Com AddIns in Excel.

I tried like:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Application.Run(@"C:\myModule.bas");
    }
```

But got errors: `Cannot run the macro 'C:\myModule.bas'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.`

Thanks in advance to people who read my question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is as simple as

```
wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Import ("C:\\Module1.Bas");
```

You do not run a module. You run a procedure in the module. To run the procedure, simply use

```
oXL.Run "Procedure Name(parameters if any)"
```

Read up more [How to dynamically add and run a VBA macro from Visual Basic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/219905). It is explained in VBA but I am sure you can easily adapt it to C#. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Thank you! I am now texting this. Will discuss more.

Comment: You need to import it first as i have shown above and then you may run it